# How to read file starting from a specific number of line within the "while read "?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

All what i want is to specify a certain number of line like this `lineNumberIs=3` and to tell while read to start out of this third line or what ever line number and fetching lines after wards to execute some commands later on the fetched lines
**Something like that**

```
 while read line from $lineNumberIs
    do
    **some commands not just echo nor printing on the screen** 
    done < $dataFile
```

Comment: And a counter would not suffice?

Comment: u mean something like for loop and counter , if that so , no sir it wont be sufficient

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # ...
done < <(tail -n "+$lineNumberIs" $dataFile)
```

`tail -n +K` (with the plus sign) tells tail to start at the specified line number (see [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tail.1.html)).

The `<(...)` bit is a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). It lets you specify a command sequence and let bash read from it like a file. It's very handy when you want to avoid the effect of the subshell created in a pipeline.

`IFS= read -r` is used to read the line exactly s it appears in the file, with no spaces or escape sequences removed.

Comment: thank u :) u mean that it is handy if i want to avoid the waste resources on reading those N unnecessary lines and start directly reading from this specific line number , did i understand u right ?

Comment: Consider this: `x=foo; echo bar | read x; echo $x` -- Would you be surprised that it outputs "foo"? If you wanted to see "bar" you would write `x=foo; read x < <(echo bar); echo $x`

Comment: yes i understand what u say about x= foo etc ....  buut actaully i dont get what is te relation between this and my question :) :)

Comment: The `tail` command lets you start reading from a specific number. The process substitution is what I called "handy" -- to relate to your question, it's a technique where the output of one command can easily be redirected into another without side effects: the while loop gets the output of tail, so the first read command gets the first line you want. Also, other people will read your question and hopefully learn something from my answer.

Comment: ok but what i want to make sure f it is that using this code it will never start reading files from the beginning and skip passing them along to while or whatever and will directly start reading from the specified line number , as if he made index to lines and start from the specified one , am i right or i misunderstand ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are unsure about. Do you mean "what iF `tail -n +$lineNumber` suddenly stops working properly"? Have you tried it?

Comment: it works and i dont doubt in ur answer i am asking abotu something else above in the previous comment and tell u what i understand ,so i understand right or also tail -n +k acts as if it reads the file from the first line and count and skip those lines until it reaches line number K then start to pass them along to while or whatever other command ? that is all :) i am asking about its working mechanism :)

Comment: I don't know how tail is implemented. You can find the source code and check for yourself. I would think that it's well tested and certainly a compiled C program will be faster than an interpreted shell script.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman :) Got to know about Process substitution.

Comment: Consider editing your answer to mention `IFS= read -r line` to avoid leading spaces/tabs getting removed.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Please execute $0 with linestoskip parameter"
        exit 0
fi
linestoskip=$1
Counter=0
dataFile='/etc/fstab'
while read line
do
        if [ $Counter -ge $linestoskip ]; then
                echo $line
        fi
        Counter=`expr $Counter + 1`
done < $dataFile
```

This script expects number of lines to skip as a parameter. You can do whatever you like to in the inner if condition.

Comment: is that the only want there is no syntax for the psuedo code that i put above in my question like while read from .... ? at all

Comment: In bash, you can use arithmetic expressions: `((Counter++))` so you don't have to call out to expr.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution -

```
tail -n +K filename
```

where K = line number from where you want to read file. This will start reading file from Kth line to the end.